# Downloading target link html to text files

Tags: python

I am completely new to python and studying Web crawling.

I am trying to download individual target link in text pages.
So far, I succeeded to extract all the target URLs I need, but have no idea on how to download all target HTML texts in multiple files. The code below just shows same article in multiple files.

Can someone help me please.

```
url = ""
r  = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
link1 = soup2.find_all('a', href=re.compile("drupal_lists"))

for t1 in link1:
    print(t1.attrs['href'])
link_data = requests.get(t.attrs['href']).text

import io
for i in link_data:
   link_data
   with io.open("file_" + str(i) + ".txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       f.write(str(i)+link_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the style of your code, starting from the point when things change:

```
for i, t1 in enumerate(link1):  # Get indices and data in one go
   link_data = requests.get(t1.attrs['href']).text
   with io.open("file_" + str(i) + ".txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       f.write(link_data)  # no str(i) because that would mess with the HTML
```